# Cannot forEach over array in Javascript with promises and console shows weird array result

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I am trying to do 2 things:

- Get a list of unique conversationId from the database
- Get the latest message for each of these conversations

However, I cannot iterate over the array with messages that is returned. I already tried taking the 2 parts of the code apart, in seperate functions. Calling one from the other, now calling them both in sequence with .then statements and nothing works. I would really appreciate some help...

This is NodeJS, with SQLite3

This is what the console shows as is being returned:

[image: Console]

This is the code to get the messages:

```
function getConversationsList(idList) 
{
    
    var c = [];
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            
            idList.forEach((id => {
                
                db.all("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (conversationId = ? AND isBroadcast = 0 AND isWarmup = 0) ORDER BY messageTime DESC LIMIT 1",{1:id},function(err,row) {
                    if(err) 
                    {
                        console.log(err.message);
                        return resolve(err);
                    }
                    row.forEach((d => {
                        console.log(d);
                        c.push(d);
                    }))
                    
                 
                }); 
                
                

            }))
            resolve(c);
        });
    
    
    
}
function convoidlist() 
{
    idlist = [];
    return new Promise((resolve) => { 
        db.all("SELECT DISTINCT conversationId FROM messages",{},function(err,rows){
            if(err) 
            {
                console.log(err)
            }
            rows.forEach((row) => {
                idlist.push(row.conversationId);
            });
            resolve(idlist);
        })


    });
}
```

This is the code that tries to loop through them, no errors, but the loop never gets inside...

```
function refreshConversations() 
    {
        convoidlist().then((idlist) => {
            getConversationsList(idlist).then((f) => {
            
            console.info(f);
            var chtml = "";
            
            
            f.forEach((e,index,array) => {
                console.info(e[index]);
                var newc = `
                <div data-id="${e.conversationId}" style="width:100%;padding:10px;margin-bottom:20px;" class="border">
                    <div width="100%" style="font-size:0.8em;"><span style="width:50%;text-align:left">${e.messageFrom}</span><span style="width:40%;">${e.messageTime}</span></div>
                    <div width="100%" style="height:100px;overflow:hidden;">${e.messageBody}</div>
                    </div>
                
                `;
                chtml = chtml + newc;
                console.log(newc);
            });
            console.log(chtml);
            document.getElementById('conversationlist').innerHTML = chtml;
        
        });
    });
    }
```

I know its a bit of a mess, it was much clearer, but I tried so much already. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing promises, regular asynchronous callbacks and `.forEach()` which just really makes it difficult to write appropriate asynchronous code.  It is best to first promisify any asynchronous operations.

If you don't have access to a version of sqlite3 that supports promises, then you can promisify specific operations you need to use (as I do here).  This would be better to do centrally in one place, but since you don't show that level of code context, I just do it locally in this one particular problem.

Then, avoid ever using `.forEach()` with asynchronous operations in the loop because `.forEach()` is not promise-aware or asynchronous-aware in any way.  It just merrily runs its loop without waiting for any asynchronous operations to finish which is very hard to manage.

Here's a promisified and restructured way to do things:

```
const { promisify } = require("util");

async function getConversationsList(idList) {
    // promisify db.all
    db.allP = promisify(db.all);

    const data = [];
    for (let id of idList) {
        const rows = await db.allP("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (conversationId = ? AND isBroadcast = 0 AND isWarmup = 0) ORDER BY messageTime DESC LIMIT 1", { 1: id });
        data.push(...rows);
    }

    return data;
}

async function convoidlist() {
    db.allP = promisify(db.all);
    const rows = await db.allP("SELECT DISTINCT conversationId FROM messages", {});
    return rows.map(row => row.conversationId);
}


async function refreshConversations() {
    try {
        const idlist = await convoidlist();
        const conversations = await getConversationsList(idlist);
        console.info(conversations);

        let html = conversations.map(e => {
            return `
            <div data-id="${e.conversationId}" style="width:100%;padding:10px;margin-bottom:20px;" class="border">
                <div width="100%" style="font-size:0.8em;"><span style="width:50%;text-align:left">${e.messageFrom}</span><span style="width:40%;">${e.messageTime}</span></div>
                <div width="100%" style="height:100px;overflow:hidden;">${e.messageBody}</div>
                </div>

            `
        });
        document.getElementById('conversationlist').innerHTML = html.join("/n");
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        // decide what to show the user here if there was an error
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. Add `db.allP()` as a promisified version of `db.all()`.
2. Use only promises for asynchronous control flow.
3. Get rid of any uses of `.forEach()` with  asynchronous operations in the loop.  Much easier to control things with promises only and a regular `for` loop with `await`.
4. In `refreshConversations()`, you call `convoidlist()`, but never use its results.
5. Centralize error reporting in `refreshConversations()`.  Low level functions should return data or error.  Higher level functions decide what to do with errors and when to log them.

Comment: @MartijnDeleij - Does this help you?  I tried to be fairly complete in offering a solution, but haven't heard anything from you on whether this helps or works for you.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!

A question though, I had .then in my code, so why did the forEach not trigger? Isn't .then not supposed only to move on when the promise is resolved?

Talking abouth this: `convoidlist().then((idlist) => {
            getConversationsList(idlist).then((f) => {`

I thought that the result of convoidlist would be passed through to getconversationslist, and then f passed on further for the loop?

Comment: @MartijnDeleij - `getConversationsList()` did not work properly.  It was calling `resolve()` on its first iteration and thus resolving the promise BEFORE the rest of the loop had completed, thus resolving with incomplete data.  To make that work properly, you can't call `resolve()` until all the iterations of the loop have taken their time to asynchronously complete.  I rewrote the code to use different structure so that was not a problem any more.

Comment: Hmm... I see, but why was the result set that I printed in the console (see image) complete then? The resolve is after the foreach loop closes...

Comment: @MartijnDeleij - The `resolve(c);` after the loop runs BEFORE any of the `db.all()` database calls have completed.  `forEach()` does not wait for asynchronous operations inside its loop to complete.